# CUDA compiler warning about unrecognized GCC pragma

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings, nvcc

There is some C++ code in a CUDA file that uses this pragma:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-result"
    void foobar()
    {
        // some code
    }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

When this CUDA file is compiled using CUDA 5.5 nvcc compiler, the host compiler stage is fine, but the device compiler stage produces this warning:

```
foobar.cu(420): warning: unrecognized GCC pragma
```

It looks like the CUDA compiler understands that this is a GCC pragma. I have no idea why it is trying to understand all GCC pragmas. Is there any method to fix this warning or make this warning go away?

Update: Please note that passing the `-Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=unrecognized_pragma"` option to the nvcc compiler does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable compiler warnings with nvcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831051/how-to-disable-compiler-warnings-with-nvcc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
-Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=unrecognized_gcc_pragma"
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. May I know where I should look for such flags? In case, I need to ignore a different warning in the future :)

Comment: Anyone using cmake can add:

`set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Xcudafe \"--diag_suppress=unrecognized_gcc_pragma\"")`

to their relevant `CMakeLists.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831051/how-to-disable-compiler-warnings-with-nvcc), you need to pass the following flag to nvcc:

```
-Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=unrecognized_pragma"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this compiler option. Surprisingly, I'm still getting the warning after I added this.

Comment: I found that I needed to specify the number explicitly, as in `"--diag_suppress=1675"`