# How to find and disable specific NVCC warning?

Tags: cuda, eigen, nvcc

Where are the NVCC codes for a specific warning listed?

Looking at other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831051/how-to-disable-a-specific-nvcc-compiler-warnings) gives the answer to use `-Xcudafe "--diag_suppress=xxx` to suppress warning "xxx", and links to a list of possible warnings [here](http://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/%7Ejimm/grizzly_docs/SSL/opt/intel/cc/9.0/lib/locale/en_US/mcpcom.msg).

However, when I have the warnings

`/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h(94): warning: __host__ annotation is ignored on a function("no_assignment_operator") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration`

and

`/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h(94): warning: __device__ annotation is ignored on a function("no_assignment_operator") that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration`

I do not find that type in the [list](http://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/%7Ejimm/grizzly_docs/SSL/opt/intel/cc/9.0/lib/locale/en_US/mcpcom.msg). Can someone point me to the page where it is, so I can find the code/name of it? I did not find it in the [documentation for NVCC](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looking for the string code for the warning, you can pass the
`--display_error_number` flag to NVCC, and get the number of that error. Then you can disable it with:

```
-Xcudafe --diag_suppress=1234
```

or whatever the error number was.

Answer (score 1):

This specific warning can be suppressed with the following flag:

```
-Xcudafe --diag_suppress=esa_on_defaulted_function_ignored
```