# What's the NVCC warning token for " 'long double' is treated as 'double' in device code"?

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings, nvcc

In this question:

[How to disable a specific nvcc compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831051/how-to-disable-a-specific-nvcc-compiler-warnings)

there's a link to a long "dictionary" mapping tokens to error messages, which seems to fit NVCC ... except it doesn't cover all warnings. Specifically, I want to suppress

```
warning: 'long double' is treated as 'double' in device code
```

... and that warning isn't in there. What's the token for it? Or perhaps - how can I determine the token given a warning string?

Note: AFAICT, it's not

```
"double" used for "long double" in generated C code
```

which is very similar.

Comment: @njuffa: Actually, it seems I only got it partially right.

Comment: Have you tried without the `=`? Some compilers use just the number, so you would write, say, `#pragma diag_suppress 191`. I think the PGI compilers use this convention.

Comment: I got this warning when trying to combine constexpr functions with literal operators (that take `long double`) with nvcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of that warning is 20208; thus, it will be suppressed if you append the following to your compilation command-line:

```
-Xcudafe --diag_suppress=20208
```

I figured this out thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142937/1593077), which explains how you can get NVCC to emit warning numbers.

However - this doesn't work:

```
#pragma diag_suppress = 20208
```

so the syntax for suppressing errors by number within the code must be different.

---

Note: **Don't mistake `diag-suppress` for `diag_suppress`.**